# The strange behavior of 'read' system function

Tags: c

The programm I tried writing should have been able to read a string of a length not longer than 8 characters and check if such string were present in the file. I decided to use 'read' system function for it, but I've come up with a strange behavior of this function. As it's written in manual, it must return 0 when the end of file is reached, but in my case when there were no more characters to read it still read a '\n' and returned 1 (number of bytes read) (I've checked the ASCII code of the read character and it's actually 10 which is of '\n'). So considering this fact I changed my code and it worked, but I still can't understand why does it behave in this way. Here is the code of my function:

```
int is_present(int fd, char *string)
{
    int i;
    char ch, buf[9];

    if (!read(fd, &ch, 1)) //file is empty
        return 0;

    while (1) {
        i = 0;
        while (ch != '\n') {
            buf[i++] = ch;
            read(fd, &ch, 1);
        }
        buf[i] = '\0';
        if (!strncmp(string, buf, strlen(buf))) {
            close(fd);
            return 1;
        }
        if(!read(fd, &ch, 1)) //EOF reached
            break;
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: after reading the `\n` did it terminate?

Comment: `strncmp(string, buf, strlen(buf))` is no different from `strcmp(string, buf)`. Maybe you meant `strncmp(string, buf, sizeof(buf))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is in the inner `read()` call. There you are not checking the return of the function.

```
    while (ch != '\n') {
        buf[i++] = ch;
        read(fd, &ch, 1);
    }
```

If the file happens to be at EOF when entering the function and `ch` equals `'\n'` then it will be an infinite loop, because `read()` will not modify the `ch` value. BTW, you are not checking the bounds of `buf`.

Comment: I did so in the previous version of my programm, but, as i said, at the end of file it reads an extra '\n', so, knowing it, i changed it. thanks for bounds

Comment: @VladislavKolesnikov: Then you should post your previous code, because  as it is, `read()` upon EOF does nothing, and `ch` is simply unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the question is *'why does `read()` work this way'* and not *'what is wrong with my program?'*.

This is not an error. From the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is  advanced  by this number.  It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right  now  (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because `read()` was interrupted by a signal.  On error, `-1` is returned, and errno  is  set  appropriately.  In this case it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any) changes.

If you think about it `read` must work this way. If it returned 0 to indicate an end of file was reached when some data *had* been read, you would have no idea how much data had been read. Therefore `read` returns 0 only when no data is read because of an end-of-file condition.

Therefore in this case, where there is only a `\n` available, `read()` will succeed and return 1. The next read will return a zero to indicate end of file.

Answer (score 0):

The `read()` function unless it finds a `EOF` keeps reading characters and places it on the buffer. here in this case `\n` is also considered as a character. hence it reads that also. Your code would have closed after it read the `\n` as there was nothing else other than `EOF` . So only `EOF` is the delimiter for the `read()` and every other character is considered normal. Cheers!